# How to group together common allowed descendants of a vertex in a tree data data structure?

Tags: php, validation, trees, abstract-class

I created an abstract class to represent a vertex in a tree structure. Later, a requirement was introduced where certain types of vertices are not allowed as descendants of certain other vertices. So I updated the class. Here is something like what it looks like:

```
<?php

abstract class AbstractVertex
{
    protected array $descendants = [];
    function addDescendant(AbstractVertex $v) {
        if (!in_array(get_class($v), $this->getAllowedDescendants())) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("not allowed as direct descendant!");
        }
        $this->descendants[] = $v;
    }
    abstract protected function getAllowedDescendants(): array;

    // ... Other methods removed for brevity
}

// Example implementation
class A extends AbstractVertex
{
    protected function getAllowedDescendants()
    {
        return [A::class, B::class, C::class];
    }
}
```

However, as new Vertex types (implementations) were added, it became apparent that some types had common allowed descendant classes, or they had significant overlap. So it became redundant to repeat the implementation of `getAllowedDescendants` for each one. I was wondering what is a good method to group together allowed descendants.

Some approaches I thought about:

- Adding an interface. For example I could add an interface like `CommonFooInterface` and all classes which should be grouped together should "implement" this interface. Then, `getAllowedDescendants` would just be `return [CommonFooInterface::class, /* other classes unique for this class */];`. I would have to modify the `addDescendant` method to loop though each element and check if $v is an instance of any of them. However with this method, the interface wouldn't have any methods and that seems wrong.
- Create a trait which implements `getAllowedDescendants` and returns the common classes. With this method, the classes with common descendants would just have to "use" this trait instead of implementing `getAllowedDescendants`. However, this only works where two classes have the same exact set of descendants.

What other approaches are there? Or would one of the ones I listed work? Or is there a better way to approach the whole thing?

#### Some clarifications:

**How much overlap is "significant"?**
In the actual application, among the derived classes of the abstract class, there are an average of 5 class names returned by `getAllowedDescendants`. Significant overlap means most of the time, 4 of the classes names are the same among all the derived class's implementation of `getAllowedDescendants`

**What is the nature of the overlap/grouping (what determines the grouping)?**
The only thing which determines grouping is the return array of `getAllowedDescendants`. Half the derived classes will have something like `return [A, B, C, D]` while the other half will have `return [D, E, F, G]`. It seems redundant to have so many instances of the same line of code.

The above answer brings up another problem. Every time a new derived class is created (say Z), I have to go to each other derived class and add the new Z as an allowed descendant where appropriate.

**Do all types share a common set of allowed types?**
Out of 10 derived classes, I would say 8 of them share one allowed descendant, and half of those 8 have another set of shared descendants, while the other half has a different set of shared dependants.

Comment: I intentionally chose the names of the methods/classes so as to be as far away from the actual code as possible. Please don't suggest alternate names.

Comment: It's a bit hard to say anything meaningful with the information provided. How much overlap is "significant"? What is the nature of the overlap/grouping (what determines the grouping)? Do all types share a common set of allowed types? You might be missing an (abstract) concept in your model. The introduction of "marker"-interfaces does might not capture the actual problem.

Comment: @Sil Added answers to your questions to my post.